# customData in Chromecast V3

Tags: swift, chromecast

I'm trying to pass customData in method:

```
    open func queueLoad(_ queueItems: [GCKMediaQueueItem], start startIndex: UInt, playPosition: TimeInterval, repeatMode: GCKMediaRepeatMode, customData: Any?) -> GCKRequest
```

Documentation says:
 * an object that can be serialized to JSON using
 * NSJSONSerialization , or nil.

Using this line of code it doesn't work (receiver have nil customData)

```
let customdataDict = ["authorizationCode" : "1241536"];

do {
let customdata = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: customdataDict, options: .prettyPrinted)
   let request =  sessionManager.currentCastSession?.remoteMediaClient?.queueLoad([item()], start: 0, playPosition:    180,
                                                                                               repeatMode: repeatMode, customData:  customdata)
}catch{
}
```

Comment: How does that code even compile? There's no variable called `prettyPrinted` declared in the piece of code included in your question. The value of the `customData` parameter in your request should be `customdata` instead of `prettyPrinted`.

Comment: sorry; i make a mistake. It doesn't work with "customdata"

Comment: Was it just a typo in your question and in your code you were already using `customdata` and the variable is still `nil`?

Comment: At Receiver side customData in event['data']['media']['customData'] is nil. In ios app contains data.